# Вывод информации с API в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

### Задачка с *

Есть HTML страничка с дивами фильмов 
У меня есть готовая страница JSON в которой   с БД MySql через NodeJs[Express]  вытаскиваются данные

Там есть все фильмы,мне нужно вытащить оттуда все поля и отобразить в HTML на чистом JS без PHP  и без фреймворков 
https://multiflex-api.herokuapp.com/api/films

```
{
"film_id": 1,
"poster_url": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0c/43/5c/0c435cab58ae6becdcbd81ad05787d26.jpg",
"tittle_name": "Spider-Man",
"genre_name": "Adventure",
"release_date": 2019,
"film_review": 5,
"trailer_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tg52up16eq0"
}
```

Код HTML :

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="movie-card">
    <img class="movie-header manOfSteel" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0c/43/5c/0c435cab58ae6becdcbd81ad05787d26.jpg">
    </img>

    <div class="movie-content">
      <div class="movie-content-header">
        <a href="#">
          <h3 class="movie-title" id="movie-tittle">Man of Steel</h3>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movie-info">
        <div class="info-section">
          <label>147 MIN | ADVENTURE</label>
          <img class="star" src="img/star.png">
          <span>9.8</span>
        </div>
        <!--date,time-->

        <div class="info-section">
          <label>Release</label>
          <span id="date-release">2019</span>
        </div>
        <!--seat-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--movie-content-->
```

[image: HMLT компонент]

Comment: Полный код HTML/CSS предоставьте

Comment: Так если у вас уже есть ExpressJS фреймворк, то сразу же в нем и рендерите свой HTML через шаблонизатор какой-нибудь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим так.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dezc3k4x/1/) (sass)

---

### Скрипт с использованием api `themoviedb`

```js
class Movies {
 
 constructor() {
  // Контейнер, в который будут помещаться нвоые элементы
  this.container = document.querySelector('.container .movies');
  
  // Блок, шаблон, макет, который будет в дальнейшем редактироваться
  this.card = document.querySelector('.movies .movie-card');
  
  // Объект всех используемых ссылок
  this.url = {
   api: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb',
   image: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400',
   link: 'https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/'
  }
  
  this.posters = [];
  
  // Удаляем блок
  this.card.remove();
  
  // Загружаем фильмы
  this.loadPosters();
 }
 
 /**
  * Загрузка фильмов
  */
 async loadPosters() {
  let response = {};
  try {
   response =  await axios.get(this.url.api);
  } catch (error) {
   return console.error(`AXIOS - ${error.message}`);
  }
  
  if (!'results' in response.data)
   return console.error('Posters not found');
  
  this.posters = response.data.results;
  this.sortPosters();
  this.setPosters();
 }
 
 /**
  * Сортируем фильмы по популярности от большего к меньшему
  */
 sortPosters() {
  this.posters = this.posters.sort((x, y) => y.popularity - x.popularity);
 }
 
 setPosters() {
  /**
   * Перебор всех фильмов
   */
  this.posters.forEach((poster) => {
   /**
    * Клонируем структуру
    */
   const cloneCard = this.card.cloneNode(true);
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем изображение
    */
   const image = cloneCard.querySelector('img');
   image.src = this.url.image + poster.poster_path;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем ссылку
    */
   const link = cloneCard.querySelector('a');
   link.href = this.url.link + poster.id;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем название
    */
   const name = cloneCard.querySelector('h3');
   name.innerHTML = poster.title;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем описание
    */
   const info = cloneCard.querySelector('.info p');
   info.innerHTML = poster.overview;
   // заголовок который при наведении покажет всю информацию
   info.title = poster.overview;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем рейтинг
    */
   const rating = cloneCard.querySelector('.footer p span');
   rating.innerHTML = poster.vote_average;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем дату
    */
   const date = cloneCard.querySelector('.footer > span');
   date.innerHTML = poster.release_date;
   
   /**
    * Добавляем блок в контейнер
    */
   this.container.appendChild(cloneCard);
  });
 }
}
new Movies();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin+Dark:400,500&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #0e1619;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  padding: 25px 35px;
}
.container h1 {
  font-family: "Palanquin Dark", sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}
.container .movies {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 40px;
}
.container .movie-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 268px;
}
.container .movie-card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.container .movie-card h3 {
  color: #1c70ec;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.container .movie-card .info {
  color: #9da3a1;
  font-size: 9px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: auto 0 0;
}
.container .movie-card .info p {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container .movie-card .footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
}
.container .movie-card .footer svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  fill: #fd0841;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.container .movie-card .footer p {
  display: flex;
}
.container .movie-card .footer p span {
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <h1>Popular Films</h1>
 <div class="movies">
  <div class="movie-card">
   <img src="">
   <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <h3 class="movie-title">name</h3>
   </a>
   <div class="info">
    <p>overview</p>
   </div>
   <div class="footer">
    <p>
     <svg viewBox="0 0 511.998 511.998" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m414.168 500.62-158.169-83.155-158.169 83.155 30.207-176.121-128.037-124.735 176.86-25.689 79.139-162.697 79.139 162.697 176.86 25.689-128.037 124.734z"/></svg>
     <span>rating</span>
    </p>
    <span>date</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

### Скрипт с использованием api `multiflex`

```js
class Movies {
 
 constructor() {
  // Контейнер, в который будут помещаться нвоые элементы
  this.container = document.querySelector('.container .movies');
  
  // Блок, шаблон, макет, который будет в дальнейшем редактироваться
  this.card = document.querySelector('.movies .movie-card');
  
  // Объект всех используемых ссылок
  this.url = {
   api: 'https://multiflex-api.herokuapp.com/api/films',
   image: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400',
   link: 'https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/'
  }
  
  this.posters = [];
  
  // Удаляем блок
  this.card.remove();
  
  // Загружаем фильмы
  this.loadPosters();
 }
 
 /**
  * Загрузка фильмов
  */
 async loadPosters() {
  let response = {};
  try {
   response =  await axios.get(this.url.api);
  } catch (error) {
   return console.error(`AXIOS - ${error.message}`);
  }
  
  if (! response.data)
   return console.error('Posters not found');
  
  this.posters = response.data;
  this.sortPosters();
  this.setPosters();
 }
 
 /**
  * Сортируем фильмы по популярности от большего к меньшему
  */
 sortPosters() {
  this.posters = this.posters.sort((x, y) => y.popularity - x.popularity);
 }
 
 setPosters() {
  /**
   * Перебор всех фильмов
   */
  this.posters.forEach((poster) => {
   /**
    * Клонируем структуру
    */
   const cloneCard = this.card.cloneNode(true);
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем изображение
    */
   const image = cloneCard.querySelector('img');
   image.src = this.url.image + poster.poster_path;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем ссылку
    */
   const link = cloneCard.querySelector('a');
   link.href = this.url.link + poster.id;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем название
    */
   const name = cloneCard.querySelector('h3');
   name.innerHTML = poster.title;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем описание
    */
   const info = cloneCard.querySelector('.info p');
   info.innerHTML = poster.overview;
   // заголовок который при наведении покажет всю информацию
   info.title = poster.overview;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем рейтинг
    */
   const rating = cloneCard.querySelector('.footer p span');
   rating.innerHTML = poster.vote_average;
   
   /**
    * Устанавливаем дату
    */
   const date = cloneCard.querySelector('.footer > span');
   date.innerHTML = new Date(poster.release_date).getFullYear();
   
   /**
    * Добавляем блок в контейнер
    */
   this.container.appendChild(cloneCard);
  });
 }
}
new Movies();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin+Dark:400,500&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #0e1619;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  padding: 25px 35px;
}
.container h1 {
  font-family: "Palanquin Dark", sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}
.container .movies {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 40px;
}
.container .movie-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 268px;
}
.container .movie-card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.container .movie-card h3 {
  color: #1c70ec;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.container .movie-card .info {
  color: #9da3a1;
  font-size: 9px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: auto 0 0;
}
.container .movie-card .info p {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container .movie-card .footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
}
.container .movie-card .footer svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  fill: #fd0841;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.container .movie-card .footer p {
  display: flex;
}
.container .movie-card .footer p span {
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <h1>Popular Films</h1>
 <div class="movies">
  <div class="movie-card">
   <img src="">
   <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <h3 class="movie-title">name</h3>
   </a>
   <div class="info">
    <p>overview</p>
   </div>
   <div class="footer">
    <p>
     <svg viewBox="0 0 511.998 511.998" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m414.168 500.62-158.169-83.155-158.169 83.155 30.207-176.121-128.037-124.735 176.86-25.689 79.139-162.697 79.139 162.697 176.86 25.689-128.037 124.734z"/></svg>
     <span>rating</span>
    </p>
    <span>date</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Обновил своё API и CORS https://multiflex-api.herokuapp.com/api/films https://multiflex-api.herokuapp.com/api/films/1 теперь когда отправляю запрос скирпт  летит на 49 41 строке где происходит сортировка

Comment: @Material сегодня оставлю второй ответ по вашему API, изначально хотел делать именно по нему, но сыпались ошибки и сервер упал вовсе, поэтому выбрал любой доступный как для примера

Comment: @Material , добавил в ответ ваше API, теперь все работает как нужно

Comment: Cпасибо,огромное за помощь) Интересно в чём же проблема была

Comment: @Material , во-первых `response.data` возвращает полученный результат, в вашем `api` не было объекта `results` , поэтому ломался скрипт, я всего-лишь убрал объект и сразу написал `this.posters =  response.data` и получил желаемый результат. Да и вся проблема собственно говоря

Comment: @Material , галкой выберите ответ который вам помог, чтобы решить данный вопрос на SO.

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```
function getCardMarkup (card) {
return `<div class="movie-card">
    <img class="movie-header manOfSteel" src="${card.poster_url}">
    </img>

    <div class="movie-content">
      <div class="movie-content-header">
        <a href="${card.trailer_url}">
          <h3 class="movie-title" id="movie-tittle">${card.tittle_name}</h3>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="movie-info">
        <div class="info-section">
          <label>147 MIN | ${card.genre_name}</label>
          <img class="star" src="img/star.png">
          <span>${card.film_review}</span>
        </div>
        <!--date,time-->

        <div class="info-section">
          <label>Release</label>
          <span id="date-release">${card.release_date}</span>
        </div>
        <!--seat-->

      </div>
    </div>
    `;
}
```

Тут ты получишь разметку для одной карточки
let cards = [ ... ]; //тут массив с даными карточек

Получаем всю разметку для карточек:

```
function getAllCardsMarkup (cards, getMarkup) {
   let markup = '';
   cards.forEach((card) => {
      markup += getMarkup(card);
   });
   return markup;
}
```

Потом пилим функцию для добавления всех карточек в контейнер:

```
function addCardsToContainer (containerEl, markup) {
   let container = document.querySelector(containerEl);
   containner.innerHTML = markup;
}
```

Ну и тут вызываем:

```
addCardsToContainer ('.container', getAllCardsMarkup(cards, getCardMarkup ));
```

Comment: Не плохо ,а запросы и получение объектов с API как делать?

Comment: Обычный AJAX запрос. Когда получишь JSON его надо будет распарсить и нарисовать из полученного массива твои карточки.